# Using file for different projects from one folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In my file explorer, my C++ project folders are like this:

... -> Documents -> C++ -> Files . . . . Projects

[In `C++` folder, there are two more folders, called `Files` and one called `Projects`. I keep all my games/projects in the `Projects` folder. Each game has its own folder inside.]

Now here's the problem: I want all my common functions (`.cpp` & `.h`) to stay in one file folder, so if I ever change it, it changes for all my games. I want to keep these in `Files`. Is there a way to achieve this, like #include [Directory]? I know I can keep a file in its own game, but I want these to be all changed easily, and my code does not need to be transferred between computers. Thanks

Comment: Most IDEs allow to add custom include paths and files to be compiled.

Comment: @PaulGötzinger I am using Microsoft Visual Studio, 2017. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp

Comment: @bolov I have seen you on my previous post. Thanks, I will look at that :)

Comment: There is no requirement that the folder structure in the IDE must match the folders on disk. You can pick a file from anywhere and add it to the Files folder.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to do it. If you have functionality that is shared between different applications (games, in your case), make a library from them and include that library in all your projects.

Comment: I am not sure how to make a library, I'm going to have to try and find that on the internet

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Visual Studio (2017)

For Source Files:
In the solution explorer right click on Sourcefiles and click   "Add"/"Add existing" and choose your file(s)

Setting Include directory:

1. In the solution Explorer right click on your "Project" and click Properties
2. On the top set "Configuration" to "All Configurations"
3. Choose in the lsit on the left "VC++ Directories"
4. Click on the Dropdown arrow on the row with "Include directories" (you might have to click once on the row for the arrow to appear
5. Click "edit"
6. Add one line for each include directory. Use the folder icon on the top to open the file explorer to choose the directories

Comment: This is the way I would do it.
You could create a single .h file in your `Projects/` directory that includes all of your project headers, and only `#include "Project-MainFile.h"` in your actual projects.

Comment: I have done this, and it wrote in include directories: C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Files\.cpp & .h;$(IncludePath) , but I can't find out how you include it.

Comment: "but I can't find out how you include it" what do you mean exactly? You still need to write `#include <name.h>`in your source files.

Comment: Do you have seperate folder for source files and headers? Because in the include directories you only need to add the header folder without file extension. e.g.: `C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Files\`